# Instância EC2 não carregando o arquivo envvars do Apache

Tags: apache

Hoje pela madrugada tive um pequeno problema com uma das instâncias da minha aplicação. Vi que o Apache estava usando muita memória, e resolvi reiniciá-lo com um `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. Entretanto, o apache não subia pelo fato que algumas variáveis que ele usa (para o usuário e arquivo de logs) não estavam sendo carregadas.

No final das contas, vi que o arquivo `/etc/apache2/envvars` não estava sendo carregado, de modo que tive que colocar as próprias variáveis dele no arquivo de configuração do Apache. No final das contas, fica a dúvida: por que esse arquivo passou a não ser carregado mais?

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

Eu estava tentando executar o processo com o usuário errado – e por isso as variáveis do arquivo `/etc/apache2/envvars` não estavam sendo carregadas.